# Alarm Manager setRepeating not waiting till time to go off

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm setting up this alarm to go off at X and current time is Y and it sending the alarm at the time Y not waiting till time X go off... Can anyone tell me why its not waiting till the proper time to go off? Sample logcat:

```
07-17 16:27:13.779: I/PROJECTCARUSO(13305): Reminder Set
07-17 16:27:13.789: I/PROJECTCARUSO(13305): Setting Alarm
07-17 16:27:13.789: I/PROJECTCARUSO(13305): ZONE_OFFSET: 15
07-17 16:27:13.789: I/PROJECTCARUSO(13305): sinceMidnight: 77233802
07-17 16:27:13.789: I/PROJECTCARUSO(13305): test now: 21:27:13
07-17 16:27:13.789: I/PROJECTCARUSO(13305): NOW: 77233802
07-17 16:27:13.789: I/PROJECTCARUSO(13305): test send: 16:28:0
07-17 16:27:13.789: I/PROJECTCARUSO(13305): SEND: 59280000
07-17 16:27:13.789: I/PROJECTCARUSO(13305): When it will kick off: 68446198
07-17 16:27:13.979: I/PROJECTCARUSO(13455): onReceive
07-17 16:27:13.989: I/PROJECTCARUSO(13455): Current time:  21:27:14
07-17 16:27:13.989: I/PROJECTCARUSO(13455): Current Mills: 1374096434004
```

Class:

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
     SharedPreferences mPreferences;
     Boolean reminder;
     String time_selected;

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
     {   
         mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); 
         reminder = mPreferences.getBoolean("frequency", false);
         time_selected = mPreferences.getString("alarm_time", "");

         if (reminder) {
             Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","onReceive");
             PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
             PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
             wl.acquire();

             // Put here YOUR code.
             String second =""+ (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000) % 60;
             String minute =""+ (System.currentTimeMillis() / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
             String hour = ""+ (System.currentTimeMillis() / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;

             String time=hour+":"+minute+":"+second;


             Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "Current time:  " + time);

             Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","Current Mills: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
             Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

             wl.release();
         } else {
             CancelAlarm(context);
         }
     }

 public void SetAlarm(Context context)
 {
     mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); 
     reminder = mPreferences.getBoolean("frequency", false);
     time_selected = mPreferences.getString("alarm_time", "");

     if (reminder) {
         Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","Setting Alarm");

         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

         // time selected from settings information
         String[] separated = time_selected.split(":");
         long  timeSelectedMillis = (Long.parseLong(separated[0])  *3600000) + (Long.parseLong(separated[1]) *60000);
         Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "ZONE_OFFSET: " + (Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET));

         Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
         long sinceMidnight = (System.currentTimeMillis()) % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

         Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "sinceMidnight: " + sinceMidnight);

         String second =""+ (sinceMidnight/1000) % 60;
         String minute =""+ (sinceMidnight / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
         String hour = ""+ (sinceMidnight / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;

         String time=hour+":"+minute+":"+second;


         Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "test now: " + time);

         Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "NOW: " + sinceMidnight);

         second =""+ (timeSelectedMillis/1000) % 60;
         minute =""+ (timeSelectedMillis / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
         hour = ""+ (timeSelectedMillis / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;

         time=hour+":"+minute+":"+second;

         Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "test send: " + time);

         Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "SEND: " + timeSelectedMillis);



         long triggerAtMillis = timeSelectedMillis - sinceMidnight;
         if (triggerAtMillis < 0) {
            triggerAtMillis = (86400000 - sinceMidnight) + timeSelectedMillis;
         }
         //System.currentTimeMillis()
         Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "When it will kick off: " + triggerAtMillis);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, triggerAtMillis, 86400000, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     } else {
         CancelAlarm(context);
     }
 }

 public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
 {
     mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); 
     reminder = mPreferences.getBoolean("frequency", false);
     time_selected = mPreferences.getString("alarm_time", "");

     if (reminder) {
         Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","CancelAlarm");
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.cancel(sender);
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the change to the alarm code. It currently works and to my knowledge works fine.

```
 public void SetAlarm(Context context)
 {
     mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); 
     reminder = mPreferences.getBoolean("frequency", false);
     time_selected = mPreferences.getString("alarm_time", "");


     Time now = new Time();
     now.setToNow();

     if (reminder) {
         Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","Setting Alarm");

         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

         // time selected from settings information
         String[] separated = time_selected.split(":");


         //Create an offset from the current time in which the alarm will go off.
         Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
         cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
         cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (int) Long.parseLong(separated[0]));
         cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, (int) Long.parseLong(separated[1]));

         Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "Time set to go off: " + cal.getTimeInMillis());
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     } else {
         CancelAlarm(context);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

just to mention the concept of "triggerAtMillis" argument:

You have to add the amount of time you want to wait to the current time.

For example, the following line first trigger the Receiver class after ten seconds, and keeps repeating it every 20 seconds:

```
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, 20000, pi);
```